# Bootstrap collapsed navbar will not react to clicks

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have tried multiple things that I have read trying to correct this issue, the big one that I've seen says that when you load you will see an error in the console, there is no error so I don't believe that one is my problem.  My navbar will collapse as the screen gets smaller, but when you click on the hamburger nothing happens.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="index">

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:700|Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./assets/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Alice Frazier's Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="d-none d-lg-block center">
                <p class="navbar-brand d-none d-lg-block nav-quote">"She believed she could so she did." -R.S. Grey
                </p>
                </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#aboutmelink">About Me</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.resume.html">My Resume</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.projects.html">My Projects</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.resume.html.html">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <p class="name">Alice Frazier</p>
    <p class="web">Web Design</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
    <img class="mypic" src="./assets/Alice.jpg" width="500" height="600">
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
    <img class="aboutmepic" src="./assets/alice2.jpg" width="350" height="450">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <p class="web" id="aboutmelink"> About Me</p>
    <p class="aboutme">Currently living and working in Indianapolis, IN. I previously worked for Dominion Dealer Solutions
        and started there as website tech support, which I loved doing, unfortunately our website team was dissolved and
        we no longer hosted websites so my next step was to support our CRM.</p>
        <br>
        <p class="aboutme">For two years I was a teacher at Sylvan Learning Center where I taught the Lego Robotics class and the Tynker Coding class.  If you would like more information on these programs check them out at the links below.</p>
        </div>
       <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4 home">
                  <p class="title">Sylvan Learning Center</p>
                  <a class="sylvan" href="https://www.sylvanlearning.com/" target="_blank"><img
                        src="./assets/sylvan_home_logo.png"
                        height="200" width="200"></a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 home">
                  <p class="title">Lego </p>
                  <a class="Lego"
                     href="https://www.sylvanlearning.com/stem/robotics-science"
                     target="_blank"><img
                        src="./assets/lego.jpg"
                        height="200" width="200"></a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 home">
                  <p class="title">Tynker</p>
                  <a class="Tynker" href="https://www.tynker.com/?t=reset" target="_blank"><img
                        src="./assets/tynker.png"
                        height="200" width="300"></a>
               </div>
            </div>
            </div>

    <br>
    <div class="icon">
            <a href="https://github.com/halliwell2046" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-github-square" style="font-size:48px"> </i></a>

            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alice-frazier-17797325/" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:48px"> </i> </a>

    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid padding">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>Alice Frazier</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-4">   
                <a href="mailto:halliwell2046@yahoo.com" class="email">halliwell2046@yahoo.com</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="tel+3173137712" class="phone">(317)313-7712</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The order of BS scripts is very important without which your click event on collapsible navbar won't work. Please check the correct order of scripts in this link and then try again: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse

Comment: I changed the order of my scripts and now the icon is gone all together

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The main thing here is Navigation bar. I haven't changed the rest. It seems that your markup was not in proper order. I have solved it for you.

Also I have used scripts from your question. I haven't changed their order.

**Run the code Snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="index">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:700|Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./assets/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>Alice Frazier's Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">My Resume</a>
      </li>    
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">My Projects</a>
      </li>    
      
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <p class="name">Alice Frazier</p>
    <p class="web">Web Design</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="mypic" src="./assets/Alice.jpg" width="500" height="600">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="aboutmepic" src="./assets/alice2.jpg" width="350" height="450">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <p class="web" id="aboutmelink"> About Me</p>
    <p class="aboutme">Currently living and working in Indianapolis, IN. I previously worked for Dominion Dealer Solutions and started there as website tech support, which I loved doing, unfortunately our website team was dissolved and we no longer hosted websites so my
      next step was to support our CRM.</p>
    <br>
    <p class="aboutme">For two years I was a teacher at Sylvan Learning Center where I taught the Lego Robotics class and the Tynker Coding class. If you would like more information on these programs check them out at the links below.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 home">
        <p class="title">Sylvan Learning Center</p>
        <a class="sylvan" href="https://www.sylvanlearning.com/" target="_blank"><img src="./assets/sylvan_home_logo.png" height="200" width="200"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 home">
        <p class="title">Lego </p>
        <a class="Lego" href="https://www.sylvanlearning.com/stem/robotics-science" target="_blank"><img src="./assets/lego.jpg" height="200" width="200"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 home">
        <p class="title">Tynker</p>
        <a class="Tynker" href="https://www.tynker.com/?t=reset" target="_blank"><img src="./assets/tynker.png" height="200" width="300"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="icon">
    <a href="https://github.com/halliwell2046" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-github-square" style="font-size:48px"> </i></a>

    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alice-frazier-17797325/" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:48px"> </i> </a>

  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid padding">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <p>Alice Frazier</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="mailto:halliwell2046@yahoo.com" class="email">halliwell2046@yahoo.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="tel+3173137712" class="phone">(317)313-7712</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```